# Is there a way I can share a disk image as a remote DVD drive?

Tags: snow-leopard, mac, install, sharing, graphics

I would like to upgrade one of my laptops to Snow Leopard but the DVD drive doesn't work.

So can I share a disk image to use it with Remote Mac OS X Install tool?

Comment: Do you have another Mac laying around that has a working DVD drive?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. One of them is quite old and the second was dropped by me by the accident. So I don't have any laptop that has a working DVD drive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - all macs support network boot. You might look at Deploy Studio for help in setting up a server that can network boot images stored on the remote machine. Borrowing a USB drive or another mac in target mode with a working DVD might be faster - but with a little set up - network booting is very doable.

Answer (score 2):

If you can manage a cheap 8GB USB flash drive, try read these links

- http://www.maciverse.com/install-os-x-snow-leopard-from-usb-flash-drive.html
- http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/02/install-snow-leopard-from-external-firewire-or-usb-hard-drive-or-how-to-upgrade-to-106-without-a-dvd-drive/